# Does multiple Ajax calls increases rendering time on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, kendo-ui, ie-developer-tools

I have created a web page using KENDO-UI & ReactJs. The page has around 8 charts and 3 grids (with 20-30 cells in each grid. No paging or sorting). Each chart and grid makes its own Ajax calls (all calls are parallel). I am NOT making using of flux or redux. Each kendo control makes its own data call and manages the data on its own (not using state). The site just works fine in chrome. All the controls renders in about 3-4 seconds. Some controls renders before other (all depends when the Ajax call was finished).

Here are the issues I observed with IE

1. It takes about 8-10 seconds to render the control in IE
2. Even though some of the ajax calls finishes early, only after all the calls are finished, all the controls gets rendered.

I know IE is generally shower than chrome but I can't understand this behavior.

What options do I have to improve the performance in IE? How can I track what is causing the issues? Can the issue be due to KENDO components(I am just guessing, KENDO components may not work well with IE when you use 8-10 components together)

Comment: how many elements in the grid and do you use paging?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: All the grids are small and have about 20-30 cells. They dont have paging or sorting

Comment: those requests are parallel or just one by one?

Comment: @YOU: they are parallel requests !!